# implode(); not separating array

Tags: php

The result is just the emails not separated at all.

```
$query  = "SELECT email FROM wp_newsman_lst_wp_users";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $new_array[$row['email']]['email'] = $row['email'];
} 

foreach($new_array as $array)
{       
   $to = $array['email'];

   $mail_list = implode(", ", (array)$to);
}

echo $mail_list;
```

The result is just the emails not separated at all.

Comment: share  us what your query gave you so we have an idea what we have, and what you are expecting

Comment: `(array)$to`? Is that an attempt to typecast something that's not an array to an array?

Comment: whats up with that another foreach, just gather them inside a container then straight up implode

Answer (score 2):

You have to take the `implode()` call outside of the foreach loop, so use this:

```
foreach($new_array as $array) {       
    $to[] = $array['email'];
     //^^ So you actually have a array
}

$mail_list = implode(", ", $to);
           //^^^^^^^ Outside of the foreach loop
```

Comment: Thank you! :D stilly stuff, new to php